# Misaligned box edge in privilege description pages

Tags: bug, design

I went to look at the privilege descriptions as a result of a different question (e.g. https://english.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit ) and the "Reputation Required" box has its right boundary drawn incorrectly:

[image: edge of box drawn in wrong location]

Comment: looks like `body.privileges-page #sidebar { width: 240px; }` is to blame (width is 220px in the sidebars elsewhere on the site)